# How to add a color picker in magento 2.1.7 system config?

Tags: magento2.1.6

I am trying to add a color picker in magento 2.1.7 using below link but it's not going to work anyone tell me that how to add color picker in magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add JavaScript color picker library in your layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**Create system.xml**

```
<config ...>
    <system>
        ...
        <section>
            ...
            <group id="my_color_group" ...>
                <field id="my_color_option" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Background Color</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Background color]]></comment>
                    <frontend_model>abc\Color\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Create the block file:**

```
<?php
namespace abc\Color\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $elementId = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $elementId.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    $elementId.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $elementId.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need to add link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/> in layout file...! @Rohan Hapani Thanks...!

Comment: ok sir... Happy to helping :)

Comment: Its working for me. Thanks