# How to add color picker in widgets in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, requirejs, widgets

i want to add color picker in widget

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190260/73525

This above link is working for system config

[image]

> same thing i want in widget as field
>
> Any one have idea about this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Add parameter to your widget:

```
    <parameter name="color" xsi:type="block" required="false" visible="true">
        <label translate="true">Color</label>
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Widget\Color" />
    </parameter>
```

2. Create Block Class (z-index needs  to be higher than modal)

```
    <?php
    
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Widget;
    
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
    use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;
    
    class Color extends Template implements BlockInterface
    {
        public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
        {
            $defaultColor = "#8ec63f";
            $value = $element->getValue() ?: defaultColor;
            $element->setData('after_element_html', '
                <input type="text" 
                    style="height: 55px; width: 55px;"
                    value="' . $value . '" 
                    id="' . $element->getHtmlId() . '"
                    name="' . $element->getName() . '"
                >
                <script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery", "jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                    $currentElement = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $currentElement.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");
                    $currentElement.ColorPicker({
                        color: "' . $value . '",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $currentElement.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script><style>.colorpicker {z-index: 10010}</style>');
            $element->setValue(null);
            return $element;
        }
    }
```

3. Add css to default.xml adminhtml (try without this step first, maybe you already have this css file)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you check official documentation? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-colorpicker.html

Comment: those things are not clear how to implement in widget..!